# Highcharts - Export PDF texts as text (and not vectorized shapes)

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, highcharts, batik

I export an Highcharts chart as a PDF file, `everything's fine`.

But when I open this chart in Adobe Illustrator (`to change some text`) :

- the characters are all `vectorized`
- so, to change the text, I have to `delete all my text` and `rewrite another one`
- thus I `lose all my style properties` that I have set in HighCharts.

---

---

Is it possible to export an `SVG` (via batik, the exporting server of HighCharts) to `PDF` with `not-vectorized text` ?

Does it exist another way to do this with ou without Batik ?

Comment: Small note: Right now Highcharts is using phantomJS to export images, not Batik. I don't know answer (unfortunately), but maybe you can get SVG (`chart.getSVG()`) and then from that SVG generate PDF using another tool? Like wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: Well, I have configure my export server to use Batik (`export_url : 'highcharts/exporting-server/index.php'`). Well it is what I see when I open the file inside the HighCharts archive. I'm gonna look at the wkhtmltopdf. I know this utility, I just hope it can convert SVG to PDF. Thanks again Pawel, you're a great help to me. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to export svg to pdf with text that can be then **edited** in Illustrator/inkscape for example.

It is thanks to [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) used in command line.

1. Install inkscape (add its installation path into `PATH` variable if you use Windows)
2. Change only one line in the `highcharts/exporting-server/index.php`

### Old one :

```
$output = shell_exec("java -jar ". BATIK_PATH ." $typeString -d $outfile $width temp/$tempName.svg");
```

### New one :

```
$output = shell_exec("inkscape -f temp/$tempName.svg -A $outfile");
```